# In Vue.js, the array updates on the webpage slower than updating a number?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

For the following Vue code:

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    name: "Peter",
    a: 333,
    arr: [1, 3, 5]
  },
  methods: {
    changeNum() {
      this.a = Math.random();
    },
    changeArray() {
      // this.arr = [...this.arr]
      this.arr[1] = Math.random();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{ name }}</div>
  <div>{{ a }}</div>

  <div v-for="num in arr">{{num}}</div>

  <button v-on:click="changeNum">Change Number</button>
  <button v-on:click="changeArray">Change Array</button>
</div>
```

There are two issues. The more minor issue is: when clicking on the "Change Array", the number doesn't reflect on the screen.  It needs to be helped by clicking on the "Change Number" button.

Why is that.  The issue could be solved by using `this.arr = [...this.arr]` in the `changeArray()` but this creates a new array and so it is not always desirable:

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    name: "Peter",
    a: 333,
    arr: [1, 3, 5]
  },
  methods: {
    changeNum() {
      this.a = Math.random();
    },
    changeArray() {
      this.arr = [...this.arr]
      this.arr[1] = Math.random();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{ name }}</div>
  <div>{{ a }}</div>

  <div v-for="num in arr">{{num}}</div>

  <button v-on:click="changeNum">Change Number</button>
  <button v-on:click="changeArray">Change Array</button>
</div>
```

The more important issue is: I can make everything into a single HTML file, and then, in Goggle Chrome's developer console, I can type

```
app.a = 123;
```

and try different numbers, and the update is fast.

But if I type

```
app.arr[1] = 456789;
```

It also updates on the webpage, but it is a bit slow.  I don't even need to do something like `this.arr = [...this.arr]` but it will still update on the page, and I wonder why.

The related question is, why is it slower?  Isn't both `app.a = 123` and `app.arr[1] = 456789` both done by JS Proxy / setter, and so they should behave the same?  I checked by using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(app, "arr")` and see that both `a` and `arr` have a `set` and a `get` function, so in theory, they should work the same and therefore, the update in the webpage should be equally fast?

**P.S. I also had a `setInterval()` to toggle between 2 images every 1 second using `<img :src="filename">` as an experiment in the code, and I thought it shouldn't have affected the array. But turned out if I commented out the `setInterval()` then the array doesn't update on the page.**

Comment: `app.arr[1] = 456789;` Is not tracked by VueJs. Instead you can use `Vue.set(app.arr, 1, 456789)`
https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating

Comment: Can somebody explain whether `app.arr[1] = 456789` in the developer's console is not supposed to update the webpage, but it is just somehow Vue.js being able to catch it? (why the button version can't)

Comment: @nonopolarity I'm not getting your behavior, I'm doing `app.arr[1] = 456789` in the browser's console and nothing is changed automatically, what is your development environment?

Comment: @nonopolarity I've updated my answer with a way to test which operation is faster, run it and see what happens in your environment. In mine it displayed only 0s and 1s, for both operations, so it seems that both take the same amount of time.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte that one is using https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js  Vue 2.6.11

Answer (score 1):

As per Vue docs:

1. [Common Beginner Gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating)
2. [List Rendering Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)
3. [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

I've edited to test your assumption that editing a number is faster than editing an array element by subtracting date objects created before and after each operation, and it seems that both take the same amount of time. Just check the console.

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    name: "Peter",
    a: 333,
    arr: [1, 3, 5]
  },
  methods: {
    changeNum() {
      const before = new Date();
      this.a = Math.random();
      const after = new Date();
      console.log(after - before);
    },
    changeArray() {
      const before = new Date();
      this.$set(this.arr, 1, Math.random());
      const after = new Date();
      console.log(after - before);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{ name }}</div>
  <div>{{ a }}</div>

  <div v-for="num in arr">{{num}}</div>

  <button v-on:click="changeNum">Change Number</button>
  <button v-on:click="changeArray">Change Array</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw it slower in the developer console and directly `app.arr[1] = 234`

Comment: @nonopolarity Have you tried `app.$set(app.arr, 1, 234)`?

Comment: please see the P.S. at the end of the question